# Safe to store private-key.pem in iOS and Android client?

Tags: flutter, security, encryption, rsa, private-key

I made an iOS & Android app in Flutter...

We need to do some client-side encryption to pass data securely for a face-id SDK integration we're using.

We have both public and private keys.

Currently I'm doing the encryption like this:

```
   final publicPem =
       await rootBundle.loadString('keys/public-key.pub');
   final publicKey = e_package.RSAKeyParser().parse(publicPem) as RSAPublicKey;

   final privPem =
       await rootBundle.loadString('keys/private-key.pem');
   final privKey =
       e_package.RSAKeyParser().parse(privPem) as RSAPrivateKey;

   final encrypter = e_package.Encrypter(
       e_package.RSA(publicKey: publicKey, privateKey: privKey));

   final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText);
   final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted);

   print('DECRYPTED IS: ' +
       decrypted); 
   print('ENCRYPTED IS: ' + encrypted.base64);
```

The `keys` directory is added to the pubspec.yaml like so:

```
flutter:
  assets:     
      - assets/
      - keys/
```

This is working... but is it safe to store my private key in the file `keys/private-key.pem` client side?

Is there a more secure way to store private keys? Or is this fine?

Thank you guys all in advance!

Comment: It's unclear who you are trying to secure this key from. If it's from the user of the application, that's impossible. Users can gain access to any data you put on their device. There's no way to solve that.  They control the hardware. If the point is to secure the data in transit, then use HTTPS. There's no need for a separate private key. If you do need to encrypt, ship a *public* key in the app. Then it's still protected in transit. But nothing will protect it from the owner of the device itself. So all of it comes down to who you're protecting against when you say "securely."